# Combining regex with html tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I have the following text from html page:

```
page = 
"""
<font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Item 1. Business/</font> Unless otherwise indicated by the context, we use the terms “GE” and “GECC” on the basis of consolidation described in Note 1 to the consolidated financial statements in Part II, Item 8. “Financial Statements and Supplementary Data” of this Form 10-K Report. Also, unless otherwise indicated by the context, “General Electric” means the parent company, General Electric Company (the Company).

General Electric’s address is 1 River Road, Schenectady, NY 12345-6999; we also maintain executive offices at 3135 Easton Turnpike, Fairfield, CT 06828-0001.

<font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Item 1A. Risk Factors</font>"""
```

I want to find obtain the text between Item 1 Business and Item 1A Risk factors. I cannot use beautifulsoup because each page has a different html tag structure. I use the following code to get the text, but it does not work:

```
regexs = ('bold;\">\s*Item 1\.(.+?)bold;\">\s*Item 1A\.',   #<===pattern 1: with an attribute bold before the item subtitle
              'b>\s*Item 1\.(.+?)b>\s*Item 1A\.',               #<===pattern 2: with a tag <b> before the item subtitle
              'Item 1\.\s*<\/b>(.+?)Item 1A\.\s*<\/b>',         #<===pattern 3: with a tag <\b> after the item subtitle          
              'Item 1\.\s*Business\.\s*<\/b(.+?)Item 1A\.\s*Risk Factors\.\s*<\/b') #<===pattern 4: with a tag <\b> after the item+description subtitle 

for regex in regexs:
    match = re.search(regex, page, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)  #<===search for the pattern in HTML using re.search from the re package. Ignore cases.
    if match:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(match.group(1), "html.parser") #<=== match.group(1) returns the texts inside the parentheses (.*?) 

            #soup.text removes the html tags and only keep the texts
            #rawText = soup.text.encode('utf8') #<=== you have to change the encoding the unicodes
        rawText = soup.text
        print(rawText)
        break
```

The expected output is:

```
Unless otherwise indicated by the context, we use the terms “GE” and “GECC” on the basis of consolidation described in Note 1 to the consolidated financial statements in Part II, Item 8. “Financial Statements and Supplementary Data” of this Form 10-K Report. Also, unless otherwise indicated by the context, “General Electric” means the parent company, General Electric Company (the Company).

General Electric’s address is 1 River Road, Schenectady, NY 12345-6999; we also maintain executive offices at 3135 Easton Turnpike, Fairfield, CT 06828-0001.
```

I think, the first regex should match the pattern but it does not

EDIT: Here is the actual htm page and way to retrieve the text:

```
# Import the libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/40545/000004054513000036/geform10k2012.htm"
HEADERS = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
print(response.status_code)

page = response.text
#Pre-processing the html content by removing extra white space and combining then into one line.
page = page.strip()  #<=== remove white space at the beginning and end
page = page.replace('\n', ' ') #<===replace the \n (new line) character with space
page = page.replace('\r', '') #<===replace the \r (carriage returns -if you're on windows) with space
page = page.replace('&nbsp;', ' ') #<===replace "&nbsp;" (a special character for space in HTML) with space. 
page = page.replace('&#160;', ' ') #<===replace "&#160;" (a special character for space in HTML) with space.
page = page.replace(u'\xa0', ' ') #<===replace "&#160;" (a special character for space in HTML) with space.
page = page.replace(u'/s/', ' ') #<===replace "&#160;" (a special character for space in HTML) with space.
while '  ' in page:
    page = page.replace('  ', ' ') #<===remove extra space
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: Are the output always in between `Item 1 Business` and `Item 1A Risk factors`?

Comment: Yes, almost always, however, if I don't use the tags, I might get wrong matches because sometimes "Item 1 Business" and "Item 1A Risk Factors" are used within the text

Comment: Have we already forgotten? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1428679

Comment: That post is irrelevant here. The first sentence of that post should have read "You can't parse COMPLEX xml/html with regex." It needs to mention that the answer is situational. Anyway, I posted a second solution. The second one should be what you're looking for edyvedy13.

Answer (score 0):

Something like as follows?

```
import re
page =  """
<font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Item 1. Business/</font> Unless otherwise indicated by the context, we use the terms “GE” and “GECC” on the basis of consolidation described in Note 1 to the consolidated financial statements in Part II, Item 8. “Financial Statements and Supplementary Data” of this Form 10-K Report. Also, unless otherwise indicated by the context, “General Electric” means the parent company, General Electric Company (the Company).

General Electric’s address is 1 River Road, Schenectady, NY 12345-6999; we also maintain executive offices at 3135 Easton Turnpike, Fairfield, CT 06828-0001.

<font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Item 1A. Risk Factors</font>"""

data = re.search('Item 1\. Business\/<\/font> (.*)(<font(.*)">Item 1A. Risk Factors)', page, flags=re.DOTALL).group(1)
print(data)
```

Comment: Sometimes there are different titles written with bold in between, that's why I also need to specify Item 1A Risk factors

Comment: Maybe it is better if I share the full code and the page

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your regex:

```
regexs = ('Item 1\.\s*Business\/(.*)',
          'Item 1\.\s*Business\.\s*<\/b(.+?)Item 1A\.\s*Risk Factors\.\s*<\/b')
```

Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I would first "parse" the HTML by greedily isolating all sequences of the type

```
<font[^>]*>([^<>]*)</font>([^<>]+)
```

which would give me something like,

```
( 'Item 1. Business/', 'Unless otherwise indicated ... CT 06828-0001.' ),
( 'Item 1A. Risk Factors', '...')
```

and takes care of the problem indicated by your comment "*sometimes "Item 1 Business" and "Item 1A Risk Factors" are used within the text*". Here, the text can only be the second element of each tuple and you basically ignore that altogether.

Then I would check what is in the first element of each match to recognize "Item 1." vs "Item 1A.". The capture cycle would start as soon as it found the first keyword, skipping the keyword itself, and stop on finding the second.

Comment: Maybe sharing the actual page and full code would work better

Answer (score 0):

**Sooo, I tried `NOT TO USE "<font>"` in the regex because you said it could vary so I hope this works. In your scenario, though, there are many ways to break the regex because XML in many cases, definitely in your case, shouldn't really be parsed using regex**

```
>>> import re



>>> string  = '''
<font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Item 1. Business/</font> Unless otherwise indicated by the context, we use the terms “GE” and “GECC” on the basis of consolidation described in Note 1 to the consolidated financial statements in Part II, Item 8. “Financial Statements and Supplementary Data” of this Form 10-K Report. Also, unless otherwise indicated by the context, “General Electric” means the parent company, General Electric Company (the Company).

General Electric’s address is 1 River Road, Schenectady, NY 12345-6999; we also maintain executive offices at 3135 Easton Turnpike, Fairfield, CT 06828-0001.

<font style="DISPLAY: inline; FONT-FAMILY: Times New Roman; FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-WEIGHT: bold">Item 1A. Risk Factors</font>'''




>>> result = re.findall('Item[\s]*1.[\s]*Business[/<]*[\S]*?[>]*[\s]+([\S\s]+?)[/<]+[\S\s]*?[>]*?Item 1A. Risk Factors', string)





#Output
>>> print(result[0])
Unless otherwise indicated by the context, we use the terms “GE” and “GECC” on the basis of consolidation described in Note 1 to the consolidated financial statements in Part II, Item 8. “Financial Statements and Supplementary Data” of this Form 10-K Report. Also, unless otherwise indicated by the context, “General Electric” means the parent company, General Electric Company (the Company).

General Electric’s address is 1 River Road, Schenectady, NY 12345-6999; we also maintain executive offices at 3135 Easton Turnpike, Fairfield, CT 06828-0001.
```

Comment: I am aware of the fact that regex is not the best solution for html in general, however I don't have any other option because the html strcture of the pages changes in Edgar website.

Comment: Yes, I read your post, which is why I made a regex solution anyway. I've been in several situations where regex is the only choice for xml and find the Python XML libraries HORRIBLE so I totally understand. See if my solution works. Let me know.

Comment: It works for the example but not for the real page itself, in my opinion, that one should work for the page, 'bold;\">\s*Item 1\.(.+?)bold;\">\s*Item 1A\.' but it does not work...

Comment: Could you post the other examples so I can see specifically what I'd be building against? It's kind of hard to get an idea without seeing all f the original text or at least more examples.

Comment: I shared the original htm, if it works for this then would work for others as well

Comment: Yes. I saw the edit. Unfortunately, there's so much variance that I'm note sure I can come up with a regex to do what you need. I thought I had one actually, but for some reason it returned None. I'll see to it after work though

Answer (score 0):

**So, you're likely in for a world of hurt given the full text of the page. In all honesty, your description of the problem is very misleading, but anywho, this might be what you're looking for, BUT IT'S MASSIVE**

```
>>> import re
>>> import requests


>>> page = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/40545/000004054513000036/geform10k2012.htm").text



>>> segment_of_page = re.findall('(?i)align=[\"]*center[\"]*[\S\ ]+?Part[\s]*I(?!I)[\S\s]+?Item[\S\s]*?1(?![\d]+)[\S\s]{1,50}Business[\S\s]{40,}?>Item[\S\s]{1,50}1A\.[\S\s]{1,50}(?=Risk)', page)



>>> parsed_data_sets = []



>>> for i in range(len(segment_of_page)):
        if len(segment_of_page[i]) > 35:
            parsed_data = re.findall('(?:<[\S\s]+?>)+([\S\s]+?)(?=<[\S\s]+?>)+', segment_of_page[i])
            for ii in range(len(parsed_data)):
                parsed_data_sets.append(parsed_data[ii])


>>> for i in range(len(parsed_data_sets)):
        if len(parsed_data_sets[i]) > 35:
            print('\n\n\n===============\n\n')
            print(parsed_data_sets[i])





#Output
===============


Unless otherwise indicated by the context, we use the terms &#8220;GE&#8221; and &#8220;GECC&#8221; on the basis of consolidation described in Note 1 to the consolidated financial statements in Part II, Item 8. &#8220;Financial Statements and Supplementary Data&#8221; of this Form 10-K Report. Also, unless otherwise indicated by the context, &#8220;General Electric&#8221; means the parent company, General Electric Company (the Company).


===============


General Electric&#8217;s address is 1 River Road, Schenectady, NY 12345-6999; we also maintain executive offices at 3135 Easton Turnpike, Fairfield, CT 06828-0001.


===============


We are one of the largest and most diversified infrastructure and financial services corporations in the world. With products and services ranging from aircraft engines, power generation, oil and gas production equipment, and household appliances to medical imaging, business and consumer financing and industrial products, we serve customers in more than 100 countries and employ approximately 305,000 people worldwide. Since our incorporation in 1892, we have developed or acquired new technologies and services that have broadened and changed considerably the scope of our activities.


===============
```

**Some of the document changed since you last extracted a string, but let me know if this works.**

Comment: I think we are almost there, from the link, I need everything under Item 1

Comment: Alrighty. I made an edit. You work for GE btw? Or just a contract with them?

Comment: no I am doing a Ph.D., just need the data for research purposes. It works for this particular question but maybe my question is more broad an hence there is no solution to this... I thought if I was using somehow "bold" html tag in the regex, I coul find a more general solution, appearently, that is not the case

Comment: No, using "bold" vs. "font" vs. any tag will NOT affect this. But really, it is hard to understand what you want because this is possible. The solution I posted above captures the paragraph text `between Item 1 and Item 2`. Do you really want the data between `Item 1 Business and Item 1A Risk factors` because what I have above does that and only a very slight change can make it capture everything between `Item 1 Business and Item 1A Risk factors`

Comment: I updated it. What is above should return only the parsed data between `Item 1 Business and Item 1A Risk factors`

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, the thing is I have multiple pages, like 9000 and I am trying to find a common pattern across them

Comment: So what I need from you is to be more specific. The first edit of this post would have captured everything between the `pattern` on the page. You then asked to get everything between `Item 1 Business and Item 1A Risk factors` so I made it limit itself to dong that. What exactly do you need? What I posted first, or something else. **Be specific**. Edit the original post to explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190694/discussion-between-edyvedy13-and-failsafe).